# React - react-router v6 nested routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-resonance-rnrr8?file=/src/App.js

The problem is when I navigate to user it will shown both `/` and `:id` despite there are no params. but if I navigate to `users/1` it will show nothing.

Need your guys help

Comment: You must use ``/users/`` as well as ``/users/:id``. To only render one of these routes at a time consider using a ``<Switch>`` or ``<Route exact path="/users/">``

Comment: @Tracer69 switch and exact not longer available on v6